WPF Conditional Binding (Bind only if ...)
I have a view model with a list of items with the Checked property.
In my WPF XAML, I create a ListBox whose items have a checkbox each in their DataTemplate.
Also, the view model has a property AllowMultiSelect. If true, the interface must allow the user to check many boxes. But if false, the interface should show RadioButtons instead and the user should select only one.
I tried a fancy XAML containing both a CheckBox and a RadioButton for the items, setting their Visibility based on the value of AllowMultiSelect with help of some derived properties.
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VMType}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 5 0 0">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowCheck, 
                                           ElementName=MyList,
                                           Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}"/>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="TableRadios"
                         Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowRadio,
                                              ElementName=MyList, 
                                              Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>

But the RadioButton (even hidden) is affecting the selection. As I click a checkbox, the Checked property of the item changes, this change reflects in the hidden RadioButton, then the radio automatically deselects other items.
Question: is there a way to "bind only if" a property is true? if AllowMultiSelect is true, I don't want to bind the radio buttons.

It's not the direct answer to your question but I think switching CheckBox and RadioButton completely will be much simpler.
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=DataContext.MultiSelect}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=DataContext.MultiSelect}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>


@DanielMöller I edited the answer (it was very close). You have to modify the ContentControl.Template

@SirRufo Thank you for editing. Switching Templates is far better.
